# Azure Active Directory B2C Proxy Address Sign On

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have an existing Azure subscription where we run our processing infrastructure. We are setting up a new app to run in the same space, but with a Azure Active Directory B2C. We have the setup working and can create new customer users that can sign in.

We have been unable to determine how to have our own users in the existing company subscription sign in to the new app (powered by the AD B2C) with the same user/email/password.

We think the answer lies somewhere between single sign on and proxy user principal names?

We should also point out that when setting up the AD B2C, an administrator user was set up for the person that set it up. Their account has an issuer of ExternalAzureAD and their user principal name is pretty much their email as a suffix on the active directory domain. Although this user is "linked" (?) to the original user in our original AD, it has a different password, etc. So also not quite what we are looking for. Ideally this user would sign into the B2C with their actual email and password (the same one used in the non B2C original AD).

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

To allow the users to login with Azure AD credentials, make sure to register the Azure AD B2C application by selecting **`Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)`**

[image]

To sign-in to the Azure AD B2C application, try using below **`authorize`** and **`token`** endpoints accordingly:

[image]

Note that, **`organizations`** endpoint will allow tenant-level login.

I created an **Azure AD user** like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/IOA0pgV.png)]

When I tried to login to the Azure AD B2C Application through Azure AD user credentials, I am able to login successfully.

And the **decoded access token contains Azure AD user information** like below:

[image]